# How to associate data with a user that has been authenticated with Google oauth?

Tags: authentication, oauth, google-authentication, google-oauth

So I am having some trouble figuring out how to implement a sign-in for my app using google oauth. Every example I see shows how to authentication the user, get their permissions and then start using the Google APIs.

I do not care about permission or using Google APIs. All I want to do is have the user sign-in to my app using google oauth instead of having to implement my own authentication system with user and passwords in the database.

After the user authenticates with their google account, then they can change settings associated with their account for my app. What is the flow i need to implement to achieve this?

How would I associated a google user with certain data defined in my own app's database? I have successfully implemented the authentication part but then what would I need to store in my DB to associate them with their actions and data. Would I need to use sessions? and then retrieve their Google+ ID, save it in the database and then use that to identify them in the database for later when they log in again?

any help is appreciated

Answer (score 0):

Once the the server validates the access token, a user account can be created in the database, saving the `Google ID` along other user details (ID, email, name etc).

If your application also supports normal registration, and an account is already present for that user (matching email), then you can just fill in the (nullable) Google ID column in order to link the account(s).